# EmptyList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Tags: clojure

I want to check whether the number of a given list is 0 or not, but my code returns EmptyList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn.

```
(defn fun [ls]
    (println ls)
    (println "hello")
    (println (count ls))
    (if (<= 0 (count (ls))) true
         (println "testing")))

#'user/fun
user=> (fun '())
()
hello
0

ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user/fun (form-init4069658807942123979.clj:5)
```

Is there any one can help me out? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

this expression:

```
(count (ls))
```

should be

```
(count ls)
```

It's trying to call the current value of `ls` as a function. When ls is the value `()` then it complains about trying to call the empty list as a function, which it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Comment: Please have a look at [empty? - clojure.core | ClojureDocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/empty_q) and [What is the correct "clojure way" to check if a collection is non empty - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118962/what-is-the-correct-clojure-way-to-check-if-a-collection-is-non-empty).

Comment: the "correct" way to write that expression is `(if (seq ls) expression-when-not-empty  expression-when-empty)